# Can we say anything about $\operatorname{Null}(A^\top)$ and $\operatorname{Null}(B^\top)$ if their Null spaces are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{A}) = \operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{B})$, where $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$.

Can we say anything, aside from dimensionality, about the relation between $\operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{A}^\top)$ and $\operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{B}^\top)$? Or are there any conditions, other than symmetry, such that the relation $\operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{A}^\top) = \operatorname{Null}(\mathbf{B}^\top)$ holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the singular value decomposition, which allows us to write $A=U_{A}\Sigma_{A}V_{A}^{T},$ and $B=U_{B}\Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T},$ for unitary $U_{A},U_{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m},V_{A},V_{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},$ and "diagonal" $\Sigma_{A},\Sigma_{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with $\sigma_{i,i}^{A/B}\geq0$ for all $1\leq i\leq\min\{m,n\},$ $\sigma_{i,j}^{A/B}=0$ whenever $i\neq j.$

The condition $\mathrm{Null}(A)=\mathrm{Null}(B)$ is saying that, if we let $v_{i}^{A},1\leq i\leq n$ denote the columns of $V_{A},$ and similarly for $V_{B},$ then (interpreting $\sigma_{i,i}$ as $0$ if $i>\min\{m,n\}$): $$\mathrm{span}(\{v_{i}^{A}:\sigma_{i,i}^{A}=0\})=\mathrm{span}(\{v_{i}^{B}:\sigma_{i,i}^{B}=0\}).$$ This really has nothing to do with the condition $\mathrm{Null}(A^{T})=\mathrm{Null}(B^{T}),$ which is equivalent to the statement above with the $u_{i}^{A/B}$ vectors replacing the $v_{i}^{A/B}$ ones, though as you pointed out, the first condition implies that $|\mathrm{Null}(A^{T})|=|\mathrm{Null}(B^{T})|$.

Another way of thinking about this, is that for any matrix $B$, we could always write its singular value decomposition as $(U_{B}U_{A}^{T})U_{A}\Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T}=\tilde{U}_{B}U_{A}\Sigma_{B}V_{B}^{T}.$ The condition $\mathrm{Null}(A)=\mathrm{Null}(B)$ imposes restrictions on $V_{B},$ but none on $\tilde{U}_{B},$ so we might think of the above expression as giving the action of $B$ with respect to the coordinates used for representing $A$ in the target space (the columns $u_{i}^{A}$), followed by an arbitrary orthogonal change of coordinates in that space, given by $\tilde{U}_{B},$ which can clearly move the vectors in the range of $B$, or in the nullspace of $B^{T}$, to any subspace of the appropriate dimension in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, which clearly can break the property $\mathrm{Null}(A^{T})=\mathrm{Null}(B^{T}).$

So if you wanted the implication you're looking for to hold, one approach might be to try to find matrices that are "simultaneously SVD-able," i.e., $U_{A}=U_{B}$ and $V_{A}=V_{B},$ or at least, there are choices of $U_{A},$ etc., with this property.

Comment: I believe what you presented is a sufficient condition for the equality to hold. I personally doubt that there is another one. I'm accepting your answer as I find it satisfying. Thanks!

Comment: It is sufficient, but I believe it can be weakened. If you split $U_{A}=[U_{+},U_{0}],$ where $U_{+}$ are the columns corresponding to nonzero singular values, $U_{0}$ are the columns corresponding to zero singular values, then you really just need $\mathrm{R}(U_{0}^{A})=\mathrm{R}(U_{0}^{B}),$ for $\mathrm{Null}(A^{T})=\mathrm{Null}(B^{T}).$ This is equivalent to $\mathrm{R}(U_{+}^{A})=\mathrm{R}(U_{+}^{B}),$ since when this holds, we may change basis for the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{R}(U_{+}^{B})$ (spanned by $U_{0}^{B}$) to make $U_{0}^{A/B}$ agree.